# Hibernate Bidirectional relationships

Tags: hibernate

How is the correct way to establish bidirectional relation @OneToMany in hibernate?

I have 3 tables useraccount, category, and item. In my item table, it holds foreign keys for useraccount and category. If I establish unidirection, it compiles with the code like this in item class:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="cat_id")
public Category getCategory() { return category;    }
public void setCategory(Category category) {this.category = category; }
private Category category;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="user_id")
public UserAccount getItemOwner() { return itemOwner;   }
public void setItemOwner(UserAccount itemOwner) {   this.itemOwner = itemOwner; }
private UserAccount itemOwner;
```

But when I try to define bidirection by adding those mapping in useraccount and category:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="USERACCOUNTS", targetEntity=Item.class, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
public Set<Item> getOwnedItems() {  return ownedItems;  }
public void setOwnedItems(Set<Item> ownedItems) {   this.ownedItems = ownedItems;   }
private Set<Item> ownedItems;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="CATEGORIES", targetEntity=Item.class, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
public Set<Item> getListOfItem() {  return listOfItem;  }
public void setListOfItem(Set<Item> listOfItem) {   this.listOfItem = listOfItem;   }
private Set<Item>listOfItem;
```

it gives me this error:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.isad.model.Item.CATEGORIES in com.isad.model.Category.listOfItem
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:684)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.isad.model.Item.CATEGORIES in com.isad.model.Category.listOfItem
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:768)
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:728)
at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:70)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1695)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1424)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:343)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:431)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:416)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
... 21 more
```

I looked at the document but couldnt find out where caused the problem. Can any one give me suggestion to fix this problem. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The annotation `@JoinColumn` indicates that this entity is the owner of the relationship (that is: the corresponding table has a column with a foreign key to the referenced table), whereas the attribute `mappedBy` indicates that the entity in this side is the inverse of the relationship, and the owner resides in the "other" entity.

According to [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/):

Since **many to one** are (almost) always the **owner side of a bidirectional relationship** in the JPA spec, the one to many association is annotated by @OneToMany(mappedBy=...)

```
@Entity
public class Troop {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="troop")
    public Set<Soldier> getSoldiers() {
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Soldier {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="troop_fk")
    public Troop getTroop() {
    ...
}
```

Troop has a bidirectional one to many relationship with Soldier through the troop property. You don't have to (must not) define any physical mapping in the mappedBy side.

To map a bidirectional one to many, with the **one-to-many side as the owning side**, you have to remove the mappedBy element and set the many to one `@JoinColumn` as insertable and updatable to false. This solution is not optimized and will produce some additional UPDATE statements.

```
@Entity
public class Troop {
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="troop_fk") //we need to duplicate the physical information
    public Set<Soldier> getSoldiers() {
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Soldier {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="troop_fk", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    public Troop getTroop() {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All your "mappedBy" of @OneToMany are wrong. its value should be the property name of the other side, try to configure as following:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="itemOwner", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
public Set<Item> getOwnedItems() {  return ownedItems;  }
```

and

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="category", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
public Set<Item> getListOfItem() {  return listOfItem;  }
```